# Redirect pg_dump output to stdout

Tags: postgresql

How to redirect `pg_dump -Fd` output to `gzip`? It requires that a directory would be specified.

```
PGPASSWORD=$db_pass pg_dump mydb -U db_user -h localhost --verbose 2>/var/log/postgresql/pgdump.log -Fd | gzip > /mnt/bulk-data/db_backup/mydb_bak.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. Use one of the other formats; ideally the `custom` format, which is automatically compressed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought there was a way.